# Timestamps change when opening the same chat twice from other chat

Tags: bug, chat, timestamps

I am usually in two different chatrooms (both designated to Java more or less) and once I accidentally opened the first room from the second one in a new tab. The result was that the timestamps were different for starred messages, the timestamps on the messages were differently set and even the avatars for the currently active users in the room where different between these windows (however this is not the case in below shown example).

Note: I assume this might be based on timezone problems. I am living in Germany with a timeshift of one hour. This one hour is to see as well in the chat.

[image: gratuitous freehand circles]

Of course marked with hand drawn red circles!

Left side is the chat that gets opened via URL. It gets started when I start my browser (batch-onliner for a few URL's I am opening usually) the right side is the one opened from another chat room using "Other rooms you are in" → RMB → "Open in New Tab".